# freeglut undefined references

Tags: compiling

can someone help me with the following problem:
I wanted to learn to develop graphical applications with freeglut.
following a guide on how to get it working on ubuntu, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install binutils-gold
```

When I try to compile some cpp code, I keep on getting undefined reference errors to the glut functions. I tried to google the problem but nothing I saw from google worked.

I use the following command to compile:

```
g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut main.cpp
```

I get errors similar to this one:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xd98): undefined reference to `glutInit'
```

This error happens happens to all the glut functions used.

Comment: How are you trying to compile your code? What exact commands are you using?

Comment: g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut main.cpp

Comment: Could you please add the exact error messages to your question?

Comment: here is one error:
main.cpp:(.text+0xd98): undefined reference to `glutInit'.


this error happens happens to all the glut functions used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place the linker options to the end of the compile command, like so:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

`g++` may process command line options sequentially, meaning that it will see that you want to link against GL, GLU and glut but no code is actually using them so they can be dropped, only then tries to compile `main.cpp`, resulting in the errors.